# Sending JSON object into google distanceMatrixService

Tags: json, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to send a JSON object to the google Distance Matrix Service in the following form:

```
{
   "1":{
      "title":"PLACE NAME",
      "zip":"14212",
      "lat":"42.654321",
      "lng":"-78.654654",
      "addr":"ADDRESS",
      "cID":"1"
   },
   "2":{
      "title":"PLACE NAME",
      "zip":"14225",
      "lat":"42.687432",
      "lng":"-78.365485",
      "addr":"ADDRESS",
      "cID":"2"
   },
   "3":{
      "title":"PLACE NAME",
      "zip":"14226",
      "lat":"42.321687",
      "lng":"-78.654968",
      "addr":"ADDRESS",
      "cID":"3"
   },
   "4":{
      "title":"PLACE NAME",
      "zip":"14226",
      "lat":"42.3268732",
      "lng":"-78.6546873",
      "addr":"ADDRESS",
      "cID":"4"
   },
   "5":{
      "title":"PLACE NAME",
      "zip":"14228",
      "lat":"43.216875",
      "lng":"-78.43243574",
      "addr":"ADDRESS",
      "cID":"5"
   },
   "6":{
      "title":"PLACE NAME",
      "zip":"14226",
      "lat":"42.584687",
      "lng":"-78.254987",
      "addr":"ADDRESS",
      "cID":"6"
   },
   "7":{
      "title":"PLACE NAME",
      "zip":"14223",
      "lat":"42.265847",
      "lng":"-78.369587",
      "addr":"ADDRESS",
      "cID":"7"
   },
   "8":{
      "title":"PLACE NAME",
      "zip":"14201",
      "lat":"42.785698",
      "lng":"-78.234565",
      "addr":"ADDRESS",
      "cID":"8"
   },
   "9":{
      "title":"PLACE NAME",
      "zip":"14225",
      "lat":"42.111111",
      "lng":"-78.222222",
      "addr":"ADDRESS",
      "cID":"9"
   },
   "10":{
      "title":"PLACE NAME",
      "zip":"14203",
      "lat":"42.333333",
      "lng":"-78.444444",
      "addr":"ADDRESS",
      "cID":"10"
   },
   "11":{
      "title":"PLACE NAME",
      "zip":"14220",
      "lat":"42.555555",
      "lng":"-78.555555",
      "addr":"ADDRESS",
      "cID":"11"
   }
}
```

I redacted some of the data being sent in (title, address, and scrambled the lat/lons), but the real data I am sending in is legitimate google maps address info.

When sending this in to the service, I keep getting the error

```
InvalidValueError: in property destinations: at index 0: not a string; and not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number
```

Is it not possible to send in a JSON object to the service?

If this has to be converted to an array, how should I go about this?

Here's the function that calls the service:

```
function calculateDistances(){

var origin = parseDeliveryAddress();
var destination = locations;

    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [origin],
        destinations: [destination],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
    }, callback);
```

}

parseDeliveryAddress grabs the users input address, and converts it to a string.

locations is the json object which is grabbed from a database.

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this by simply pushing the json data into an array with:

```
var addresses = [];

    jQuery.each(destination, function(){
        addresses.push(this.addr);          
    });
```

Distance Matrix Service now accepts this.